# TypeError: find_element_by_xpath() got an unexpected keyword argument 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, python

Python 3.8 (32-bit) interactive window [PTVS 15.9.18254.1-15.0]

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser=webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\Python27amd64\msedgedriver')

browser.get("https://canyonoakscc.com")

browser.find_element_by_xpath(onclick="document.getElementById(&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039")
```

The code I'm trying to execute is Book A Tee Time

Comment: This is the code I'm trying to emulate    "><a href="/book-tee-time" class="arrow" onclick="document.getElementById(&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039;).submit(); return false;">Book A Tee Time </a></li>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to click on that element.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    browser=webdriver.Edge(executable_path='C:\Python27amd64\msedgedriver')
    
    browser.get("https://canyonoakscc.com")
    
    click_here = browser.find_element_by_xpath("&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039")

    click_here.click()
```

Comment: Kunal Your solution throws this error  selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression &#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039 because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=85.0.564.51)

Comment: Bipul Your solution throws this error     selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@onclick, 'document.getElementById(&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039)')]"}
  (Session info: MicrosoftEdge=85.0.564.51)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to locate the `anchor` tag with the specified onclick set, this should help:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@onclick, 'document.getElementById(&#039;members-module-book-tee-time&#039)')]")
```